# How to remove white background from dialog box with custom image background?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

[image] [image]

i wanted to create a custom dialog like the first image for a Android game.after a lot of trial and error i was able to create a dialog box that's looks like the 2nd screenshot image.
even though it looks identical to what i wanted to achieve,but it shows white pixels around the image even though it is a png.

**How can i remove the white pixels from the screenshot dialog box image and make it look identical to the first image?**

Comment: yes... it is possible!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code to ur dialog box to make it transparent

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

or

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawableResource(R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: FYI You need to use dialog box, this won't work on alert box.

Comment: I tried your solution there are no white pixels now, but there is a grayish color where there was white before.please refer to below link for the current screenshot.  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uv9vrvrsunx8ylr/Screenshot_2016-07-04-20-45-56.png?dl=0)

Comment: @pavitran there is something else is being displayed behind ur img, remove ur "Time's up" img. and screenshot the alert box

Comment: yeah it looks good without the "Time's up" img. here's the screenshot [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2gohqd0qp8uri3/Screenshot_2016-07-04-21-07-25.png?dl=0) but my "Time's up" img is transparent too see this image [bg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvpfdwtnxnct24j/dialog.png?dl=0)

Comment: @pavitran Are you using Dialog Box or Alert Box?

Comment: i'm using dialog box like so `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);`

Comment: @pavitran Okay, im not sure whats going on. You can use an alternative; **Dialog Fragment** http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-dialog-fragment-example

Comment: thanks i'll check those solutions. and also why does people keep downvoating the questions,stackoverflow bans us from asking further questions if we have more downvoted question,which makes it hard for starters like me get the answers for our questions.

Comment: @pavitran People downvote is due to the way you asked the question, take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve